# How to deal with routing conflicts on WebAPI - string IDs vs action + id

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

I am hosting a REST API using Web API on .NET 4 (WebAPI version 4.0.30506 on nuget).  To allow for more elaborate attribute routing, I've also included [attributerouting.net](http://attributerouting.net/) in my solution.

I have 2 attribute routes that are conflicting.  The reason for the conflict is that we are querying by a string identifier in one call, and querying by a string action + numerical identifier in another. The message thrown in the HTTP response reads `Multiple actions were found that match the request`.  Here are sample queries to demonstrate both of them:

```
1) http://example/api/libraries/?libraryId=some_library (some_library is a string identifier)

2) http://example/api/libraries/bookStatus/1 (1 is the library database ID)
```

I've been struggling with different ways to make this work.  My current controller signatures look like this:

```
[GET("api/libraries/?libraryId={libraryId}", Precedence = 2)]
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public Library QueryLibraryByLibraryId(string libraryId){}

[GET("api/libraries/bookStatus/{libraryId:long}", Precedence = 1)]
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> QueryBookStatus(long libraryId){}
```

I can see why the routing might get confused: How does it know that the string identifier of `"bookStatus/1"` is invalid is a fine question to ask. However, I figured this should be easier to define some constraints around.

How do I resolve these conflicts while maintaining this type of signature structure?

Comment: What happens if you switch Precedence values? If the first one can take precedence whenever there's a match and fall back to the second one only when the string doesn't have `libraryId=...`, it seems like that should work.

Comment: Is the `?libraryId={libraryId}` part actually doing anything? I'm not convinced you can *have* query strings in routes like this, but I'd also expect that query string to be mapped to (and from) that method signature anyway.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Changing the precedence values didn't have any result at all. What you mentioned was my initial assumption as well..

Comment: @Rawling The ?library={libraryId} function worked until I added the 2nd function.  I didn't have the GET attribute (WebAPI assigned it automatically by prefixing the function name with "Get"), but otherwise it was the same.

Comment: Have you tried changing the first route to just `GET("api/libraries",...)`?

Comment: Or `"api/libraries?{libraryId}"`? (looking at http://attributerouting.net/#optional-params)

Comment: I had a play with this and I only got the error you got when I had everything massively misconfigured and it was the out of the box, default controller routing that was routing everything. Basically, with one controller action it was routing everything under that controller to that action by default; with two actions, it couldn't decide how to route anything. Do you have something like `routes.MapRoute(name: "Default", url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });` anywhere?

Comment: @Rawling My only configured route is the simple default one.  ``config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("API Default", "api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });``

Comment: @Jim Try going back to just having your original method on your controller, then remove that `MapHttpRoute` call and see if you can get to that method at all.

Comment: What you're describing seems to me that web api default routing is taking over your rauting. Do you actually have the attribute routing configured by calling config.AddRoutesFromAssembly or config.AddRoutesFromController or config.AddRoutesFromControllersOfType? these are required by attribute routing.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that default WebAPI routing convention is matched before attribute routing.

You should set the attribute routing as ***default routing***, which means in *WebApiConfig.cs*,
you need to call

`config.Routes.MapHttpAttributeRoutes`

firstly before calling other

`config.Routes.MapHttpRoute`.

One more optional thing to mention, you don't need to specify the libraryId in the query part for the first method.

It can be done automatically.

```
        [GET("api/libraries", Precedence = 2)]
        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public Library QueryLibraryByLibraryId(string libraryId) { }

        [GET("api/libraries/bookStatus/{libraryId:long}", Precedence = 1)]
        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> QueryBookStatus(long libraryId) { }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I will test this ASAP.  I'm already calling MapHttpAttributeRoutes, but it's after MapHttpRoute.  Why is that causing conflicts?

Comment: All the routes will be used to match request in their added order. Your request sample can be matched by default routing(MapHttpRoute), however conflict in default routing will throw. So attribute routing will never take its turn if exception is thrown in default routing. So you should put attribute routing in first place and then attribute routing will be used to route firstly before default routing is called.

Answer (score 3):

I have tested your configuration with a sample project. And it seems you made error in one of the following areas. I am giving a rundown of what I did, please verify that you did the same to make it work -

**One** Remove Default Routing.

By default ASP.Net MVC routes are configured to serve with default values. This is the first thing that I removed to make sure my attribute routing is working. **We can bring the default route later on but for now remove it so that it does not interfere**. So remove the following or comment from `WebApiConfig` class -

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "DefaultApi",
      routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
      defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
 );
```

So my route config look like this -

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        //config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        //    name: "DefaultApi",
        //    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        //    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        //);

        // Uncomment the following line of code to enable query support for actions with an IQueryable or IQueryable<T> return type.
        // To avoid processing unexpected or malicious queries, use the validation settings on QueryableAttribute to validate incoming queries.
        // For more information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=279712.
        //config.EnableQuerySupport();

        // To disable tracing in your application, please comment out or remove the following line of code
        // For more information, refer to: http://www.asp.net/web-api
        config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
    }
}
```

This is important because and this is the main reason the route is getting messed up. **I will explain later why.**

**Two** Register Attribute Routes.

I used the following code to register my attribute routes, this how my application start looks like in Global.asax -

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

        //code to register attribtue routes
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(config =>
        {
            config.AddRoutesFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        });

        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

**Three** Now since we have the routes in places lets make our controller methods perform tests -

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        ......

        [GET("api/libraries", Precedence = 2)]
        public string Get_1(string id)
        {
            return "value :" + id;
        }

        [GET("api/libraries/bookStatus/{id:long}", Precedence = 1)]
        public string Get_2(int id)
        {
            return "value :" + id;
        }

        ......
    }
}
```

and Guess what?  both the url works -

`/api/libraries/?id=2`

[image]

`/api/libraries/bookStatus/5`

[image]

AS of now you have the solution. But lets see why this happened? Described below -

**The Reason**

First notice that the default route was supposed to serve by the name of the controller and also the name of my Controller does not correspond to the path used, this is because I wanted to show you why this happens. Since our attribute routing is working, we are serving the urls even though our api controller name is different from routes. But the default route cannot do that and thus the error.

First lets verify that our route for default is not working by going to `/api/{controller}/{id}` and so we browse - `/api/values/5` and it says 404. Its obvious cause we removed it.

[image]

Lets bring back our old MVC default route that we removed at **One** -

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Now lets try again and VOILA!!. We got our error :) -

[image]

Do I need to explain more ? :) ... I think you got the reason

But wait... we need our default routes right? OK then just register it after our attribute routes and that is the solution... all works at this point -

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        //code to register attribtue routes
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(config =>
        {
            config.AddRoutesFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        });

        //after attribute routes, now we can safely register our default routes
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```